# Tensorflow model dir very big, results are not accurate, estimator training need to be executed a lot of times

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, regression

I have simple CSV training data set with 5403 rows, like this:

```
4;4;8
10159;33589;43748
12353;32085;44438
12120;23906;36026
1001;788;1789
788;1001;1789
```

It's basically random generated numbers (two first in row, third is addition result) first number (val1) + second number (val2) = third number (result). Data set has been generated once, so each execution time the data set is the same. Test set for evaluation is done in the same way. My code is:

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
        feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
        hidden_units=[100, 100],
        model_dir='model_2'
    )
    classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(train_x, train_y, len(train_x)), steps=350)

    classifier.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(test_x, test_y, len(test_x)), steps=50)

    expected = [8, 12, 200, 81, 200, 211, 299, 250, 1789, 45000]
    predict_x = {
        'val1': [4, 6, 100, 40, 100, 30, 99, 100, 1001, 40000],
        'val2': [4, 6, 100, 41, 100, 181, 200, 150, 788, 5000],
    }

    predictions = classifier.predict(input_fn=lambda: eval_input_fn(predict_x,
                                                                    labels=None,
                                                                    batch_size=440))
```

Problems and questions:

When I "ask" this code first time about result for 4+4 it not gives me correct result (it gives me for example 8.943672). When I run it again it gives me still incorrect result but closer to correct each time I run it. When I run it hundreds of times then I finally got expected result.

Question 1: Why this code "can't learn" at once ?

Question 2: I have in my training set row: 4;4;8, why the mechanism didn't get the result from data set instead of doing calculations ?

Question 3: As I mentioned, I've run this code hundreds of times, my model dir `model_2` is now over 1,1Gb size while trainig data set is 90,2 Kb, why is so big ? Can I reduce it ?